# Optional merge on relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am new to Cypher and I am trying to learn it through a small project I am trying to set up.

I have the following data model so far:
[image]

For every `Thought` created, I connect `Tags` through `Categories`.
The `Categories` only serve as intermediate between the `Tags` and `Thoughts`, this is done to improve querying, prevent `Tag` duplication and reduce relationships between the objects.

To prevent creation of new `Tags` with the same value, I thought of the following query:

```
CREATE (t: Thought {moment:timestamp(), message:'Testing new Thought'})
MERGE (t1: Tag{value: 'work'})
MERGE (t2: Tag{value: 'tasks'})
MERGE (t3: Tag{value: 'administration'})
MERGE (c: Category)
MERGE (t1)<-[u:CONSISTS_OF{index:0}]-(c)
MERGE (t2)<-[v:CONSISTS_OF{index:1}]-(c)
MERGE (t3)<-[w:CONSISTS_OF{index:2}]-(c)
MERGE (t)-[x:CATEGORIZED_AS{index: 0}]->(c)
```

This works fine, except for one thing: the `Thought` receives a relationship with all created `Categories`. 
This I understand, I define no restrictions in the MERGE query.

However, I do not know how to apply restrictions to the `CATEGORIZED_AS` relationship?

I tried to add this to the bottom of the query, but that does not work:

```
WHERE (t)-[x]->(c)
```

Any idea how to apply a restriction like I need in my case?

### EDIT:

I forgot to mention the unique connection of a `Category`:
A category is connect to a fixed set of `Tags` in a specific order.

E.g I have three tags:

- work
- tasks
- administration

The only way the `Category` matches the `Thought` is if the `Category` has the following relationships with the `Tags`:

- work <-[:CONSISTS_OF {index:0}]-(category)
- tasks <-[:CONSISTS_OF {index:1}]-(category)
- administration <-[:CONSISTS_OF {index:2}]-(category)

Any other order of relationships is invalid and a new `Category` should be created.

Comment: Could you explain a little more about what you mean when the thought receives a relationship to all created categories? From the looks of it, you may want to be clearer whether you want to `create` or `merge` your nodes. It would probably make more sense to `merge`  the category with the relationships so that you don't duplicate categories, or even just create one category in the db...

Comment: I see what you mean now. This is a really interesting issue - to do with the merge syntax. I'll write up an answer.

Comment: Thank you very much :D Glad you understand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The Problem: Use of `MERGE`**

`MERGE` will try and find a pattern in the graph, if it finds the pattern it will return it, else it will try and create the entire pattern. This works individually for each `MERGE` clause. So, this works great and as expected for `(n:Tag)` nodes, since you only want one tag for each word in the graph, but the issue comes with the later in your query when you try to merge a category.

What you want to do is *try and find this `(c:Category)` that is connected to these three `(t:Tag)` nodes with these r.index properties on the relationship `(:Tag)-[r:CONSISTS_OF]-()`*. However, you're running four merge clauses which do the following:

```
MERGE (c: Category)
```

Find or create any node `c` with the label `Category.

```
MERGE (t1)<-[u:CONSISTS_OF{index:0}]-(c)
MERGE (t2)<-[v:CONSISTS_OF{index:1}]-(c)
MERGE (t3)<-[w:CONSISTS_OF{index:2}]-(c)
```

Find or Create a relationship between that node and `t1`, then `t2`, `t3` etc.

If you were to run that query, and then change one of the tags to something different like "rest", and run the query again, you'd expect a new category to appear. But it won't with the current query, it'll simply create a new tag, then find the existing `(c:Category)` node in that first `MERGE` clause, and create a relationship between it and the new tag. So, rather than having two categories each linked to three tags (with two tags being shared), you'll just have four tags all linked to one category with duplicate indexes on your relationships.

So, what you actually want to do is use `MERGE` to find the complex pattern like below.

```
MERGE (t1)<-[:CONSISTS_OF {index:0}]-(c:Category)-[:CONSISTS_OF {index:1}]->(t2),
  (t3)<-[:CONSISTS_OF {index:2}]-(c)
```

Annoyingly, that will give you a syntax error, as cypher can't currently merge complex patterns like that. So, here comes the creative bit.

**Solution 1: Conditional Execution with `CASE` and `FOREACH` (Easy)**

This is quite a handy goto for these kinds of situation, see the commented query below. You'll essentially split the merge up, use `OPTIONAL MATCH` to try and find the pattern, and then use a little trick in cypher syntax to `CREATE` the pattern if we find it doesn't exist.

```
CREATE (t: Thought {moment:timestamp(), message:'Testing new Thought'})
MERGE (t1:Tag{value: 'work'})
MERGE (t2:Tag{value: 'abayo'})
MERGE (t3:Tag{value: 'rest'})
WITH *
// we can't merge this category because it's a complex pattern
// so, can we find it in the db?
OPTIONAL MATCH (t1)<-[:CONSISTS_OF {index:0}]-(c:Category)-[:CONSISTS_OF {index:1}]->(t2),
  (t3)<-[:CONSISTS_OF {index:2}]-(c)
// the CASE here works in conjunction with the foreach to 
// conditionally execute the create clause
WITH t, t1, t2, t3, c, CASE c WHEN NULL THEN [1] ELSE [] END AS make_cat
FOREACH (i IN make_cat |
  // if no such category exists, this code will run as c is null
  // if a category does exist, c will not be null, and so this won't run
  CREATE (t1)<-[:CONSISTS_OF {index:0}]-(new_cat:Category)-[:CONSISTS_OF {index:1}]->(t2),
    (t3)<-[:CONSISTS_OF {index:2}]-(new_cat)
)
// now we're not sure if we're referring to new_cat or cat
// remove variable c from scope
WITH t, t1, t2, t3
// and now match it, we know for sure now we'll find it
// alternatively, use conditional execution again here
MATCH (t1)<-[:CONSISTS_OF]-(c:Category)-[:CONSISTS_OF]->(t2),
  (t3)<-[:CONSISTS_OF]-(c)
// now we have the category, we definitely want 
// to create the relationship between the thought and the category
CREATE (t)-[:CATEGORIZED_AS]->(c)
RETURN *
```

**Solution 2: Refactor Your Graph (Hard)**

I haven't included a query here - although I can do if requested - but an alternative would be to refactor your graph to attach tags to categories in a ring (or chain - with a final member marker) structure, so that you can merge the pattern straight away without having to split it up.

Since the categories are in an order, you could express the data like the below, in one `MERGE` clause.

```
MERGE (c:Category)-[:CONSISTS_OF_TAG_SEQUENCE]->(t1)-[:NEXT_TAG_IN_SEQUENCE]->(t2)-[:NEXT_TAG_IN_SEQUENCE]->(t3)-[:NEXT_TAG_IN_SEQUENCE]->(c)
```

This might seem like a neat solution at first, but the problem is, that since tags will belong to multiple categories, if tags are shared between categories you will need to either:

1. create a composite index to identify categories and store this as a property of the sequential relationships so you know which relationships to follow in your path (i.e., so you can always find one, and only one, sequence of tags for a category)
2. still link each tag to the categories it is in and query on this pattern (to allow you to find that single path like in #1)
3. Use an intermediate node to achieve the same as 1 and 2
4. All of the above and more.

As you might have guessed, this will make your query much more complicated than it needs to be quite quickly. It could be fun to try, and may suit some use cases, but for the time being I'd stick with the easy solution!

Comment: Dom, thank you very much for taking to time to help me along. I will try the easy way first, because I cannot move on learning Cypher without getting this out of the way. Maybe later I will understand the limitations and come back here to try option two. :D

Comment: I had a small issue on this part:
   CREATE (t1)<-[:CONSISTS_OF {index:0}]-(cat:Category)-[:CONSISTS_OF {index:1}]->(t2),
     (t3)<-[:CONSISTS_OF {index:2}]-(cat)           This is because c is already bound ofcourse, so I changed it to cat, and it works great!!

Comment: Ah yes, sorry! I remember correcting that when I tested it but mustn't have copied it over, sorry! Glad it worked out okay, and happy to help! :-)

Answer (score 1):

My solution to your problem, is to enforce that every Category has a unique, consistently reproducible id. In your case, add a `cid` or `id` field, where the value is something along the lines of `tag1<_>tag2<_>tag3<_>`. (`<_>` is used because the chances of that being part of a tag are zero. If `_` is an invalid tag character replacing `<_>` with `_` will do just fine).

This way you can lock onto a category node without having to know anything about the nodes it is attached to. Essentially, the unique id IS your merge logic. This can even be dynamicly built up in Cypher using [reduce](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/list/#functions-reduce). I usually also have a `value` field as a "pretty print display id value".

When running the final Cypher, you would Merge on each node alone by instance id, use Set for non node-defining fields, then use Create Unique to make make sure there was one and only one relation between the nodes.

Comment: TBH this seems to me like a less dynamic solution. I might want to expand the `Tag` properties, and your solution will cause me a lot of work. It does answers the question though, so thank you for your input!

Comment: Having a composite index for the category may be useful in the long run as a way to quickly search for a category if required (depending on use case), but in this case you'd still have the issue with the conditional merge - i.e., you would have to link categories to tags *iff* the category doesn't yet exist, so doesn't quite solve the problem.

Comment: @Abayob That's ok, it might be a useful solution to someone with a similar problem.

Comment: @DomWeldon For me, I Merge all nodes by their instance id, then Set their non-unique fields, and then use Create Unique to make sure there is "1 and only 1" relationship connecting the nodes. For me, doing it this way means that running a cypher twice will always have no affect, and will work exactly the way I want regardless of what nodes my or may not exist already. But I also had the requirement of only knowing the generated instance ids would be unique, and not knowing for sure anything else about the state of the graph.